# how to deserialize JSON data on the server side after sending from client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

this way i am sending my json data

this way i construct my json data like below one

---

```
function Post(carousel, first, last, per_page, page) {
  var json = "{'Name':'" + $("input[id*='txtName']").val() +
            "','Subject':'" + $("input[id*='txtSubject']").val() +
            "','Email':'" + $("input[id*='txtEmail']").val() +
            "','Message':'" + jQuery.trim($('.message').val()) + "'}";



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Feedback.aspx/SaveData",
        data: json ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           'here is my success code'
        }
    });
}
```

so i just want to know how to write the code in the server side with c# which will deserialize my json data to a feedback class.

my feedback class has same property like name,subject,email,message etc. so tell me how to fill the feedback class with deserialization.

please help me with code. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to do anything. ASP.NET will do it for you. Just define your method with the appropriate parameters, and it will work automagically:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveData(string Name, string Subject, string Email, string Message)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Or since you already have this class defined, you just need to wrap your javascript fields around an object:

```
var json = "{'msg':{'Name':'" + $("input[id*='txtName']").val() +
            "','Subject':'" + $("input[id*='txtSubject']").val() +
            "','Email':'" + $("input[id*='txtEmail']").val() +
            "','Message':'" + jQuery.trim($('.message').val()) + "'}}";

[WebMethod]
public static void SaveData(Feedback msg)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: +1 yes joe is absolutely correct in you case you need not do deserialization even if you have created object,i have edited it now for json instead of msg previously for the webmethod parameter

Comment: @abhi: Actually, the way I have it is correct. If you pass in an object containing those four fields, then your method will have the same 4 parameters. If you pass in a JSON object with one field, which in turn has four of its own fields, the name of the one field will match up with the name of the parameter in C# (msg), and the field names of the JSON object will match up with the property names of the `Feedback` class. The `json` variable name does not get sent into the C# code.

Comment: @user728750: One thing that would make life a little easier would be to use the JSON2.js library. It will let you take a JSON object and convert it to a string, so you don't have to worry about that part - you can take a regular JSON object, call `JSON.stringify(someobj)`, and it will give you a string that you can use in your AJAX call.

Comment: yes joe json2.js is an ideal solution to work with jQuery+Ajax+Asp.Net

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following library:

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

You can deserialise the JSON like so:

```
string json = "{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Subject\":\"subject\",\"Email\":\"email\",\"Message\":\"message\"}";
FeedBack feedBack = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeedBack>(json);
```

....

```
public class FeedBack
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can make use of the built in .NET Framework JSON serializer class:

[JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
FeedBack feedBack = serializer.Deserialize<FeedBack>(json);
```

Comment: Here u show a different json format so i think my json data will work or not? var json = "{'Name':'" + $("input[id*='txtName']").val() +
            "','Subject':'" + $("input[id*='txtSubject']").val() +
            "','Email':'" + $("input[id*='txtEmail']").val() +
            "','Message':'" + jQuery.trim($('.message').val()) + "'}";
u show like string json = "{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Subject\":\"subject\",\"Email\":\"email\",\"Message\":\"message\"}";
so please tell me do i need to build json data according to ur style like \"Email\".......please guide. thanks

Comment: The slashes are just used to escape the double quotes in the string. I have checked the same code using single quotes like so "{'Name':'name',.....}" and it works fine. However valid JSON should use double quotes. See: [Keep your JSON valid](http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), check out the example at the [end of this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

try this:
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
feedback fb = new feedback ();

fb = JSONSerializer.ConvertFromJSON<feedback>(json);

class JSONSerializer
{
    public static string GetJSONString(object data)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(data);
    }
    public static T ConvertFromJSON<T>(String json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
}
```